# How can i change Feature Importance so it isn't random anymore? in Python

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am doing feature selection using feature importance which is based on a decision tree.

```
#Feature importance (source: https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e)
X = df.iloc[:,1:31]  #independent columns
y = df.iloc[:,0]    #target column = diagnosis

model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
print(model.feature_importances_) #use inbuilt class feature_importances of tree based classifiers

feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh', color="lightskyblue")
plt.show()
```

But the results change everytime i start it again, probably somewhere there is a random number somewhere. Is there a way to set this once and then keep it the same so that the results don't change everytime the kernel is restarted?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I think I managed it using:
model = ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=1)
is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `random_state` parameter of `ExtraTreesClassifier` to some value. In this case you will get reproducible results.
For example:

```py
model = ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The number I use doesn't matter, right?

Comment: Well it's just an initialization of randomness in classifier. With different numbers you'll get different results. But for each particular number you will always have the same result.

Comment: okay awesome, got it. Thank you! Have a nice evening

Comment: One more question.
#Hyper-Parameter Tuning for K-Nearest Neighbor (source: https://www.kaggle.com/arunimsamudra/k-nn-with-hyperparameter-tuning)
param = {
    'n_neighbors':  range(1, 25, 2), #Number of neighbors
    'p': [1,2], # 1= manhattan distance, 2= euklidean distance
    'weights': ['uniform', 'distance']}

knn_grid = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(random_state =1), param_grid=param, cv=5, n_jobs=5,verbose=1)

knn_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(knn_grid.best_params_)

I wanted to do this here. but random state doesnt work with KNN.. can you help me with this?